# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf Security not recognized

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i've been trying to use thymeleaf's security tags but i can't get them to work.
This is my security class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/css/**", "/js/**", "/image/**", "/", "/myAccount" };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                .deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll().and().rememberMe();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Index.html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping
                            Cart</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"
                        class="nav-link" th:href="@{/login}">My Account</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"
                        class="nav-link" th:href="@{/myProfile}">My Account</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                        sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
```

My problem is that both the nav-items called My Account are showing on the page and i guess the tag sec:authorize doesn't get recognized or something like that or i'm clearly doing something wrong:( Do i need to do any other configurations? I'm using spring boot 2, i've tried solving this in different ways from changing the version of thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 to adding a bean in the spring context but it's still not working:(

Comment: Could you please paste UserSecurityService? The problem may be that you are authenticated when you shouldn't be. Your thymeleaf code looks fine. Just to be sure that it is working try to view page source and you should not see sec:authorize on your html elements.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I was able to solve the problem by changing the spring boot version to 1.5.8 but i'm still not sure what's wrong with spring boot 2

Comment: I copied your code and started it         <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version> and everything works as expected. OBS : My UserSecurityService just implements loadUserByUsername and returns null.

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot auto configuration, an instance of `SpringSecurityDialect` is not auto configured. Therefore, you are having this problem. Try adding a bean of `SpringSecurityDialect` like below, and I hope, it will work.

```
@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect securityDialect() {
    return new SpringSecurityDialect();
}
```